# Order items is empty when customer logged-in

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer

I'm use following code to catch order information in this Observer : `"sales_order_save_after"`

```php
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

 $orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData();
 $orderId = $orderData['increment_id'];
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
 $orderItems = $order->getItems();       

 foreach ($orderItems as $item) {

     error_log(print_r($item->getData(), true));

 }


}
```

When I place order as guest customer it logs information of all items, But when I Login as a customer and placing order it doesn't log anything because **"items"** Array is **empty**.

How can I get item information from order of customer that is logged-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's related to customer being logged in or not, but I think order items are not persisted yet, as you're retrieving new order object. Also you should never use objectManager directly.

Try updating your code to this:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 $orderItems = $order->getItems();       

 foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
     error_log(print_r($item->getData(), true));
 }
}
```

Observer already has order object